# How to set initial state in top level react component with redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want something like this:

```
MyMainComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState()=>{
    let state = store.getState();
    return Object.assign([], state, initialDataset: this.props.initialDataset)
  }
})
```

and somewhere else in the code:

```
let store = createStore(reducers, {
  foo: "default"
  initialDataset: []
})

export const MyApp = ({ initialDataset }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MyMainComponent initialDataset={initialDataset}  />
  </Provider>
)
```

I haven't found any examples that come close to this yet. I am not sure it's even possible.

Edit: I wanna add that `MyApp` is called in a ruby helper with `initialDataset` instanciated server-side.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. Initial state gets set in redux already, so no need for setting initial state in component unless you specifically want to have two copies of your state (not recommended)

Comment: Inside your `connect`ed components state from redux will appear as props so you would just say `getInitialState() { return { state: this.props.state } }`

Comment: @azium, the code that creates the store is in my assets, `initialDataset` is initialized server-side, I can't hardcode it in my .js files. I NEED to have my initial dataset in the state.

Comment: But... redux *is* your state. I think what you want is to dispatch an async action which fetches your initialDataset from the server which will populate your redux state, no?

Comment: that would be a workaround but that means one more route and one more request to the server.

Comment: I was thinking I could do a dispatch passing the initialDataset from the props as argument and then filling the state with it. I would put it in `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As azium highlighted, it doesn't seem necessary to duplicate the redux store's state into your top-level component's state.

If your concern is to instantiate the `store` with the `initialDataset` client-side, you can add a `script` tag in your HTML with a global variable :

```
// assuming you are in a erb template
<script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = <%= JSON.generate(initial_dataset) %></script>
```

Then in your assets, you can use it like so :

```
let store = createStore(reducers, {
  foo: "default"
  initialDataset: window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || []
});
```

You can find an example of that in the redux docs : http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html

Hope it helps